# Deux questions de prononciation sur « Booz endormi »

Tags: poésie, liaisons

La prononciation de « Booz » tout d'abord : pour des raisons de versification, il semble nécessaire de considérer que Booz a deux syllabes : dans la plupart des vers ou le nom apparaît, l'alexandrin n'est possible qu'en attribuant deux syllabes à Booz. Je suppose donc que l'on prononce « bohoz ». Exemples :

> Booz s'était couché de fatigue accablé ;

ou encore

> Booz était bon maître et fidèle parent ;

Et cependant [cet articulet](http://www.chilton.com/paq/archive/PAQ-01-071.html) sur la prononciation de *zoo* affirme que l'on prononce *Booz* en une seule syllabe. Comme ledit billet considère également que l'on prononce *zoo* « zo », ce qui n'est pas la norme ([Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3540), [Girodet et Thomas](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/vous-dites-a3737989)), je suis néanmoins enclin à garder mon idée initiale et à prononcer « bohoz ». Quelqu'un peut-il confirmer ?

---

Ma deuxième question porte sur le vers suivant :

> Le croissant fin et clair parmi ces fleurs de l'ombre

À l'oral, au quotidien, je n'hésiterais pas, nasaliserais *fin* et ne ferais pas la liaison ; mais serais-je également fondé ici à dénasaliser et à prononcer « le croissant fine et clair » ?

Comment: Pour répondre à la deuxième question, la liaison est interdite après le ET (c'est une règle générale).

Comment: Après, oui (par exemple "avant et après") ; mais avant ? Je ne suis pas sûr : on dit par exemple "les enfants petits (z) et grands".

Answer (score 3):

Il est évident que pour des raisons de diction des alexandrins il faut prononcer Booz sur deux pieds. Je ne le transcrirais cependant pas « bohoz » qui impliquerait l’introduction d'un h aspiré mais « bo-oz » qui  se traduirait par un **allongement** du /o/ et non pas par la prononciation de deux /o/ l'un après l'autre.

D'ailleurs écoutons deux grands acteurs français dire ce [poème de Victor Hugo](http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/victor_hugo/booz_endormi.html) extrait de *La légende des siècles* et nous constatons que malgré leurs dictions différentes du texte ils prononcent *Booz* de la même façon.
[Jean Vilar](http://fr.redmp3.su/19012787/jean-vilar-booz-endormi.html)
[Gérard Philippe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TtrDhkt1Ic)

Par ailleurs il s'agit d'un nom propre mentionné dans la Bible dont la prononciation en hébreux est /bō`az/ donc deux syllabes distinctes.

Je ne vois absolument pas ce qui justifierait une liaison entre « fin » et « clair », alors que  j'adhère à la diction des deux acteurs qui font la liaison dans le vers précédent :

> Les astres émaillaient le ciel profond‿et sombre ;

Comment: Je suis d'accord pour la prononciation de Booz – j'avais d'ailleurs écouté la lecture de Gérard Philippe, que je n'avais pas du tout aimée, ni pour l'intonation, ni pour la versification ; j'aime mieux celle de Vilar, mais tout ne me convainc pas non plus. Pour *fin et clair*, en revanche, ma question était de savoir s'il était possible – licite, même – de la faire, et que l'un et l'autre de ces acteurs ne la fassent pas ne tranche pas la question.

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Je ne vois pas de règle l'interdisant par contre faire la liaison gêne pour moi la compréhension. Certes la césure se fait automatiquement après « clair » mais je n'arrive pas à prononcer le vers sans faire une légère pause après « fin » pour arriver à donner la même importance à ces deux adjectifs d'une syllabe. En faisant la liaison j'aurais l'impression de donner plus d'importance à clair (finale du groupe de souffle).

Answer (score 2):

Je ne peux pas en distinguer la raison, mais je prononce spontanément zoo en allongeant sur le o (comme le décrit @Laure), comme j'ai lu spontanément Booz en deux syllabes. Est-ce une affaire d'accent ou y-a-t-il une règle derrière? Bonne question.

Il me semble justement que l'objectif de la licence poétique (puisque le mot Booz est tiré de vers) permet ce genre d'exception. Ceci implique que la prononciation de Booz en deux syllabes (ou du moins avec un o allongé), afin de respecter l'alexandrin, relève plus de la volonté de l'auteur que d'une règle.

Answer (score 0):

Tout à fait d’accord. Booz a deux syllabes, le nom s’est également écrit Boaz. L’écriture hébraïque n’indique pas les voyelles. Les alexandrins doivent avoir douze pieds faute de quoi la poésie est bancale.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French SE.  Tu répètes un peu les autres réponses.  Pourrais-tu donner des informations sur l'hébreu par exemple comme c'est unique ?  Voici le [tour] et le centre [help].